# Making the equation $x^3+1=3xy-y^3$ explicit

Tags: graphing-functions, implicit-function

$$x^3+1=3xy-y^3$$
How do I turn this equation into the form of $y=f(x), x\neq1$? When I graph the above, it looks like $y=-x-1$.
I've tried factoring and can't seem to make it work.

Note: The original question asked for the closest distance between $x^3+1=3xy-y^3$ and $(6,7)$. I could probably substitute values into the equation to see how it looks like and realise that it looks like a line, but I want to try to get an explicit equation.

Comment: Essentially it is a cubic equation in y to be solved.

Comment: $x^3+1=3x(-x-1)-(-x-1)^3,$ so what ?

Comment: When $x=1$, you get $y^3-3y-2=0$ which has $2$ solutions: $y=1$ and $y=-2$. This means the equation cannot be written as a function $y=f(x)$ unless you exclude the point $(1,1)$.

Comment: I think you meant $y^3-3y+2=0$ instead. Good point though, I'll include it in the question

Comment: How do I solve the cubic equation in y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist the following formula of Euler:

If
$$
x^3+y^3+z^3=3xyz\Leftrightarrow (x+y+z=0\textrm{ or }x=y=z)
$$
Hence you equation is written
$$
x^3+y^3+1^3=3x y\cdot 1\Leftrightarrow (x+y+1=0\textrm{ or }x=y=1)
$$
QED

REVISED. The formula of Euler read as
$$
x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)[(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2]
$$
If one makes the evaluations it easily follows.

Comment: This only applies for x=y=1 though. They should be equal for all values of x and y

Comment: I add the complete formula of Euler for not confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y:=u-x-1$. Then

$$y^3-3xy+x^3+1=u(u^2-3(x+1)u+3x^2+3x+3)$$

The root $u=0$ is of course $$y=-x-1.$$ Then the discriminant of the quadratic equation is

$$-3(x-1)^2$$ and the only real solution is

$$x=1\implies y=1.$$